# Why does it seem the inner curls within a surface always cancels in order for greens theorem to be true

Tags: vectors, mathematical-physics, vector-fields, stokes-theorem, curl

Im trying to learn aerodynamics in general for my course. Every video i see to derive the concept of greens and stokes theorem shows how the inner curls within a surface area cancel to 0 and its only the outer surface edge that has a contribution from the vectors. Hopefully the image better shows this…

[image: Curl within a surface]

But what if there was a segment where the curl wasn’t exactly the same as any adjacent to it? Surely the chance of the curl been the same on each segment is practically never seen? Why and how did this assumption come from?

Essentially I don’t see how say there was a vector field stated below, how the outer edge describes the inner surface…

[image: another vector field example]

Comment: This is a very reasonable question to make. Perhaps you can give more context regarding the level of the course, course material and so on, so people know what kind of answer would better suit you.

Comment: Your sketch contains both some clockwise curl near the center and some counter-clockwise curl between the center region and edges. These must cancel out.

Comment: @aschepler ahh yes i see it now. Appreciate the response

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We are not really comparing "adjacent" line segments; all we are saying, more precisely, is that the circulation along a line segment is the same as itself. This is hard to see from a visual aid like the one in the question, because in order to make the diagram legible, we're forced to draw the arrows a bit away from the boundary they correspond to.

However, for example, the two arrows highlighted in red below really both mean "take the circulation along the line segment highlighted in orange".

[image]

That segment is the segment where two adjacent "cells" of the division touch. If we take the counterclockwise circulation around the boundaries of both cells, then both circulations will include the circulation along that segment, but in opposite directions. Line integrals along the same segment in opposite directions are negatives of each other, so these two circulations cancel; this does not require any coincidental relationship between the values of the vector field in different places.

Comment: This is helpful, but what if say where you drew the boundary devision, the section on the right had a clockwise rotation?

Comment: Are you talking about the orientation of the boundary, or about the rotation of the vector field? The orientation of the boundary is something we choose, when we decide which integral to take. The rotation of the vector field, meanwhile, is not something that's drawn in the diagram at all! Rather, we have all these counterclockwise curves to indicate that we are measuring the *amount of counterclockwise circulation along them* of some vector field that we do not draw.

Comment: so if its the amount of clockwise rotation thats measuered per division (which i think i do understand). What if the vector field happens to be differet in one segment to another, surley then the inner curls wouldnt cancel out?

Comment: I think the question is about the orientation of the boundary. If we orient the outer boundary counterclockwise, why does this imply that we have to orient all the inner boundaries counterclockwise as well to obtain the same integral?

Comment: @Georgekirby When we ask "does the circulation along the orange segment in the picture cancel out?" we don't need to compare it to any other segments; it is simply the case that the two adjacent cells there *both* measure circulation along that same segment, but in opposite directions. The same is true for all other interior segments in the diagram; only the outside boundary doesn't cancel out.

Answer (score 9):

Imagine you know that the fundamental theorem of calculus:

$$\int_a^b f'(x) dx = f(b) - f(a)$$

*only holds for differentiable functions defined on $[0,1]$*. Then how would you show, say, that for differentiable $f : [0,3] \to \mathbf{R}$ the theorem holds?

We can define $f_k(x) =f(x+k)$, translation of $f(x)$ to the left by $1$, and observe that $f_k(x)$ restricted to $[0,1]$ is just $f(x)$ on $[k,k+1]$. But we know that we can use the fundamental theorem of calculus on $f_k(x)$ restricted to $[0,1]$, so that:

$$\int_0^1 f'_k(x) dx = f(k+1) - f(k)$$

Moreover, the integral is the area under the curve, we have that:

\begin{align*}\int_0^3 f'(x)dx &= \int_0^1 f'_2(x)dx + \int_0^1 f'_1(x)dx + \int_0^1 f(x)dx\\ &= f(3) - f(2) + f(2) - f(1) + f(1) - f(0)\end{align*}

Which is just $f(3) - f(0)$! In this way we have used the fundamental theorem of calculus on a "tiling" of $[0,3]$, and observed that because our tiles only overlap at their ends, the sum of the integrals ends up becoming a telescoping sum, and everything except the first and last term cancel. In effect, we have used the fundamental theorem of calculus, which we pretended only works for $[0,1]$, to prove the fundamental theorem for $[0,3]$.

The proof of Green's Theorem is exactly the same, but now it's two-dimensional. We first prove Green's theorem for squares, then tile our region with squares that overlap on their ends. Then just like how the interior ends in the one-dimensional case cancel, the interior boundaries in the two-dimensional case cancel as well. Thus the only thing that matters for Green's theorem is the outer boundary of the region integrated over, which is precisely what we wanted to show.

Comment: This definitely helps me understanding whats going on with greens theorem, but I still dont see how the image supports this, what if the curl was in the opposite direction for an adjacent tile?

Comment: In the above telescoping sum, the sign of a left-hand endpoint is always positive, and the sign of a right-hand endpoint is always negative. This is because we have chosen the orientation of left-to-right for each line segment, and this is what allows the sum to telescope and cancel. Similarly, we will always be applying the same direction of rotation to each tile in Green's theorem, so (for example) the sign of a left-hand edge will be opposite of the sign of a right-hand edge. Thus again the values on the edges, when summed and therefore telescoped, cancel.

Comment: If you are concerned about whether some tile might have a different orientation--- that can happen, but it doesn't in the proof because we have freedom over which orientations we choose. We pick an orientation of the entire shape, then tile it and then *induce the same direction* on each tile. This is what allows for the cancellations.

Answer (score 2):

This can be explained by a small example.

Say you take a wooden plank amd apply an anticlockwise rotational force (like curls given in the picture) at different points. Consider a point P between any two points of application of torque (rotational force), say A & B. The tangential forces experienced at the point P due to torque at A and B are opposite to each other.

The opposite tangential forces cancel out each other in the plank and what the plank will experience is the total rotational force applied as though applied only at the edges where the tangential forces don't cancel out.

This is a very blank simplistic explanation I got.